# Getting not defined error when converting a nested list into list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Code without List comprehension which is working fine

```
for i in range(1, int(b)+1):
    for j in list(combinations(a,i)):
        print("".join(j))
```

My attempt to list comprehension

```
[print("".join(j)) for j in list(combinations(a,i)) for i in range(1, int(b)+1)]
```

Error message:
`NameError: name 'i' is not defined`

Comment: What is combinations? Is it a dictionary?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of uncertainties in your code. What is b? What is a? As @Riptide aksed, what is combinations? The syntax of the list comprehension is incorrect. Please specify what result you want, and what you're not understanding.

Comment: `print()` isn’t documented to return a value, you will get `None`.

Comment: What is the obsession with one-liners? Your for-loop code doesn’t return a list so why does your attempt at a one-line version create a list?

Comment: I, personally, highly discourage nested comprehensions, since they a real pain to read and understand

Comment: @DavidZ provided a very nice answer (than he later deleted) explaining that the order of the `for` clauses need to be in the same order as you were doing in the `for` loops version: `[print("".join(j)) for i in range(1, int(b)+1) for j in list(combinations(a, i))]`

Comment: @Adirio Thanks :-) I only deleted it because I thought the linked duplicate question covers the issue well enough, and I wanted to avoid splitting people's attention by having essentially the same thing posted both here and there.